# Extraction of label names from images

Tags: machine-learning, python, text-extraction, form-recognition

I have images of forms & I need to extract label names from the images like Name, Email, Address, Phone Number, etc. that require user input.

I'm looking for approaches & tools that can help me extract such text. Bard does the job well but it doesn't provide Python APIs that I can use within my application.

Can someone suggest libraries/tools/programming approaches for this problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you use HTML tags to get the information. That got me confused about what the problem actually is.

Comment: I meant extracting text embedded within HTML tags like <button> & <hr>. That is where we have the label names. This approach isn't text extraction from images, but one that I tried to get the label names.

Comment: Then the question is about images, but you also have an HTML representation of the form in the image?

Comment: Not in all cases. So I'm mostly focusing on specific text extraction from images. I'll remove the HTML part from my question to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you will need to translate the image to text. To do so, you would need an OCR library. I would suggest using PaddleOCR, as the implementation is relatively easy, while the results are satisfying. After you have done that you will no longer have a picture to work with and now you have text. Your second step is Text Mining. Now depending on the text you have you will have to pick a model. It is not necessary to use a LLM model. It is possible that a simpler model will also do the task. If you have tags or names before the input you can use them for your task by using the Named Entity Recognition technique (NER).  This will work if you have NAME: John Doe, EMAIL: J.D@gmail.com . If you do not have tags, it will be harder and you will probably need an LLM model.